# Row of Cell with TextWrap doesn't auto size with EPPlus

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm creating a downloadable spreadsheet version of a report in my web app using EPPlus. I know cells will have text that will be too long for a default cell width but I want the cells to have the default width so I am setting the WrapText property of the Style cell range to true.

The text does wrap but the row containing the cell remains at the default height so all but the last line of the wrapped (now multi-line) text is hidden.

Is there anyway to force the spreadsheet to auto size the row height and show all the text.

Here is some code which reproduces the behaviour I don't want. I am viewing the spreadsheet in LibreOffice and OpenOffice.  The problem only shows up in LibreOffice - it works fine in OpenOffice but I would rather it worked in Libre as well.

I've tried different combinations of setting the style before and after setting the content.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        using (var package = new ExcelPackage()) {

            ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");

            sheet.Cells[2, 2].Value = "Long piece of text";
            sheet.Column(2).Style.WrapText = true;

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Clear();

            this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            this.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",string.Format("attachment;  filename={0}", "ExcellData.xlsx"));

            this.Response.BinaryWrite(package.GetAsByteArray());

            Response.Flush();
            Response.Close();
            Response.End();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try `sheet.Cells[sheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();`. Not sure if this also fixes cell height...

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to leave the column width untouched. AutoFitColiumn will resize the column.

Comment: I'm starting to think its just a bug in Libre.  I suspect that when you edit the file thru the GUI the row height is calculated and cached.  The other spread sheets might be recalculating on load but Libre relies on the cache.  Either that or EPPlus should be calculating and caching when the change is made but isn't.  I was hoping that there was some way to force EPPlus to recalculate and flush through the API.